# I think it should be passive voice, but it is not!

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

This is an extract from a [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boarding_school):

> It is claimed that children may be sent to boarding schools to **give**
> more opportunities than their families can provide.

I think the sentence is wrong and the verb "give" should be made passive:

> It is claimed that children may be sent to boarding schools **to be given**
> more opportunities than their families can provide.

Comment: Your version is better. It's Wikipedia, so I'd go ahead and make the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an unusual wording, but it is grammatically correct: **give** can be either transitive (requiring an object) or intransitive (without an object). The usage in the first sentence is intransitive.

It is certainly possible to change the sentence to use passive voice, but it's best to avoid passive voice unless there is a compelling reason to do so. I would simply add an object to the active voice sentence:

> It is claimed that children may be sent to boarding schools to give **them** more opportunities than their families can provide.